# Подскажите как сверстать кнопку при помощи СSS и HTML% как на картине

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите как сверстать кнопку при помощи СSS и HTML% как на картине.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на фон картинку поставьте и не мучайтесь, не выдумывайте

Comment: @HamSter может он хочет какое то ноу хау

Comment: Сверстать можно, но на мой взгляд лучше перевести в svg и просто вставить как картинку. Хотя я бы лучше отказался от такой "симпатичной" кнопки -_-

Comment: А чем кнопка не устраивает?:)

Comment: Ну такие кнопки в последний раз в 2003 использовали, я просто критичный эстет, прошу прощения :)

Comment: Тут бывает и "похлеще", дело не в кнопке. Не стоит извиняться=)

Comment: Если что, можете писать мне, я помогу :)

Comment: А мне зачем помогать? Я не вопрошающий, лишь мимо проходил=))

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.btn-cart {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FB911F;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 75px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
}

.btn-cart:before {
  content: 'Icon';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 64px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #FB911F;
  border: 6px solid #FB911F;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-cart:hover {
  background: #00f;
}

.btn-cart:hover:before {
  border-color: #00f;
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn-cart">Корзина (0)</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое